# Heteroskedasticity-robust F statistics in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, fstat

The F-stat from my standard model (multiple regression) is invalid since heteroskedacity is present. I have used The HAC function and computed the robust SE and new p-values, but how do I find the new robust F-stat?  Is there a function in matlab to do this in a simple way?